# How to redirect the user to password recovery page with forms authentication

Tags: asp.net

I am a beginner of asp.net..I currently have a login page with forgot password link button on the bottom of the screen.  I am also using forms authentication to prevent an unauthorized user from accessing the other pages.  The authentication seems to be working fine except for one thing. It prevents the user from accessing the password recovery page once the user click on the link button.  How do I allow all users access to the login/password pages and also prevent them from viewing the other pages if they are not authenticated?

The code below is to prevent from other anonymous view other pages without access. But i got no idea on how to allow them to access password recovery page...

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/Presentation/Display/Login.aspx" name=".ASPNETAUTH" protection="All" path="/" timeout="120" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" slidingExpiration="true"/>
</authentication>
<!-- This section denies access to all files in this application except for those that you have not explicitly specified by using another setting. -->
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `<location>` element to apply settings to a specific path, then add an `<allow />` for non-logged-in users.

For example:

```
<location path="PasswordRecovery.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: so where should i put this code in web config? under the <authentication mode="forms> ? or above?

Comment: @DEN: At the bottom. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx  The `<location>` element adds (almost-) arbitrary new configuration for specific folders or files.

Comment: @slarks, im still unable to access the passwordrecovery page. The url turn to be http://localhost:4772/Presentation/Display/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/Presentation/Display/PasswordRecovery.aspx but the page still remain at login.aspx

Comment: @DEN: Did you put in the correct application-relative path in the `<location>` element?

Comment: @slarks, yup,i did. refer back to the code i posted, did i write anything wrong?the <authorization></authoritzation> shouldn't been written twice?one under <authentication form> , one under <location path...> ?

Answer (score 2):

```
<location path="Presentation/Display/PasswordRecovery.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

This allows anonymous users to view your password recovery page. You might want to do the same for the directory where your CSS and/or image resources are stored, in case they are required by your login page and/or your recovery page.

Comment: thanks for your reply,but where should i locate this code in webconfig?

Answer (score 2):

Use Location:

```
<location path="passwordrecovery.aspx">
   <system.web>

      <authorization>
          <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: At the same level as system.web, outside of that element obviously.  It's essentially a first level element.