# how to access to password recovery page?

Tags: asp.net

I have the authentication which will redirect the unregister user to Login.aspx. At the bottom of the page,there are a link button will redirect the user to forgotPassword.aspx
With having the authentication, i discover it don't allow the unregister user to go forgotPassword.aspx but staying in the same page.
so some expert have shown me this code..

can anyone provide me the code in web.config here?

some expert have provided me the code..but i find no where to locate this code in web.config, none of them tell me where to locate it..[click this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300354/how-to-redirect-the-user-to-password-recovery-page-with-forms-authentication)  ..im abit confused.. please provide me whole web.config code so i can have overall idea :( thankss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put it between the main configuration elements:

```
<configuration>
    <!--You have other configuration elements here-->

    <location path="passwordrecovery.aspx">
       <system.web>
           <authorization>
               <allow users="*"/>
           </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Just don't forget to accept an answer from your original question.

**UPDATE**

It is important to note that the above assumes that the `passwordrecovery.aspx` file is located in the same location as the `web.config` file that contains that above configuration. If the `passwordrecovery.aspx` file is located somewhere else, you will need to change the `path` attribute.

So, assuming the `web.config` is in the root of your site, and the `passwordrecovery.aspx` file is in the folder `/Presentation/Display` then you will need to update the code as follows:

```
<configuration>
    <!--You have other configuration elements here-->

    <location path="Presentation/Display/passwordrecovery.aspx">
       <system.web>
           <authorization>
               <allow users="*"/>
           </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Another alternative is to keep the original configuration provided, but create it in a new `web.config` file that is located in the same folder as the `passwordreovery.aspx` file.

Comment: It shouldn't matter but I would put it after all the other configurations.